# Code 400 Bad Request on Android Stack Exchange Google Login

Tags: bug, android-app, login

When I try to login to the Android Stack Exchange app with my Google account I get [image: an error]. I tried it on multiple networks and on cellular but it gives me the same error consistently.

I also tried multiple phones running Oreo and Pie, tried reinstalling a few times on each and it always gives me the same error. I don't have a rooted device and no ad-blocker is running. When I try to log in with Chrome on the same phone it works normally and no error occurs.

How can I log into my account on Android?

Comment: The app is pretty much dead. Better use a browser.